# Adaptive bit rate streaming not working in nginx-vod-module in NGINX server

Tags: nginx, streaming, winginx

I have installed Nginx and configured VOD for adaprive streaming using nginx-vod-module. While requesting the master.m3u8 file I'm getting same ts files served for different network bandwidth.

The master.m3u8 file has the following content:

```
 #EXTM3U
 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAMID=1,BANDWIDTH=1914317,RESOLUTION=1280x544,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2"
  http://localhost/content/Input.mp4/index-v1-a1.m3u8
```

The Nginx configuration is:

```
   location /content {
        vod hls;
        vod_mode local;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types application/vnd.apple.mpegurl;

        expires 100d;
        add_header Last-Modified "Sun, 19 Nov 2000 08:52:00 GMT";
    }
```

How can I get adaptive bitrate enabled using nginx-vod-module and what's the best way to verify it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You encode multiple versions of your `Input.mp4` with different resolutions/bitrates. The aspect ratio should be the same. Eg: `Input_high.mp4`, `Input_low.mp4`
2. You edit the master `m3u8` playlist and add each rendition with its specific bitrate and resolution:

   ```
   #EXTM3U
   #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=...,RESOLUTION=...,CODECS="..."
   /content/Input_low.mp4.m3u8
   #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=...,RESOLUTION=...,CODECS="..."
   /content/Input_high.mp4.m3u8
   ```
3. When the `nginx-vod-module` receives a request for a `filename.mp4.m3u8` it automatically segments `filename.mp4` for `HLS` and creates the playlist for you. Eg: `/content/Input_low.mp4.m3u8` for `/content/Input_low.mp4`

Comment: master m3u8 is dynamically served and generated . I dont want to pre create any playlist and segment files . I have kept only a mp4 file .

Comment: @RachitGupta You *must* create the master playlist manually, aka the one that holds the stream information. The media playlist is automatically created for each file. And you must encode your file in multiple `mp4` variants. See: https://www.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Serving-Media-with-NGINX-Plus1.pdf

Comment: What does this means? "encode your file in multiple mp4 variants" . Do i need to put multiple mp4 of different qualities?

Comment: @RachitGupta Yes, the module doesn't encode it just repackages in `HLS`

Comment: We are expecting dynamic adaptive bit-rate HLS is it available in nginX-Plus?

Comment: "The NGINX Plus module performs real-time segmentation, packetization, and multiplexing from the MP4 file container to HLS/MPEG-TS **without recoding the content.**" From: https://www.nginx.com/products/streaming-media-delivery/